# how do I use the google sheet import function to import Linkedin Company's About Page info?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried the following function; but, I am unable to fetch the company info into google sheet. Can please someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Example:
Cell D4 contains the following link:
https://www.linkedin.com/company/linkedin/about/

Here is the function:

```
=importxml(D4,"//*[@id='ember71']/section/dl/dd[2]")
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you quote bumps into an authentication page. The various import functions in Google Sheets cannot get through authentication or paywalls. They are evaluated at Google's servers rather than in your browser, so any authentication you may have completed in your browser does not help here.